# moses error : Can't read /phrase-model/moses.ini

Tags: moses

I have just installed moses 2.1 , while trying the sample model I am getting error: Can't read /phrase-model/moses.ini

command I am sending is echo 'das ist ein kleines haus' | /Users/kagrawal/Desktop/tools/moses/bin/moses -f /phrase-model/moses.ini < phrase-model/in > out  from my sample-models folder.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the sample-models directory along with phrase-model/moses.ini
for example like this:

~/mosesdecoder/bin/moses -f sample-models/phrase-model/moses.ini